Run script on quit with iTerm2
How can I run a script on quit with iTerm2? I don't just want to run it whenever I minimize or close the window, but specifically on quit.
This is because I want to run Amazon Q when I start iTerm (easy enough with open '/Applications/Amazon Q.app', but then also close Amazon Q when I'm done.
This can usually be done with q quit in the command line, but I am unsure how to run specifically on quit.

Does the shell you are running support executing an rc file when it exits?

@MarcWilson I'm using ZSH. I don't think it supports that, but honestly I have no idea. A Google search yields little info, and also wouldn't that cause problems if I have multiple iTerm windows/tabs open?

You could use a tool like Keyboard Maestro to watch for when iTerm quits and then quit Amazon Q. This does require an additional tool which may not meet your use case.

@AnonyoNoor So each of the iTerm tabs is supposed to have a copy of this GUI app running?  Or is there only one copy running?  BTW... 5 sec of Google points to zsh supporting a.zlogout file, which may or may not do what you want, since you're asking it to kill a GUI app.

man zshall is your friend here -> $ZDOTDIR/.zlogout. Of course, this will fail if you run more than one shell (tab/window in iTerm), unless you close all of them at once at the end.

@MarcWilson Amazon Q is a AI coding assistant which can be used from the command line. So the use case here would appear to be launch iTerm, launch Amazon Q, do work in multiple terminal windows, quit iTerm, quit Amazon Q. Thus it would not work to have Amazon Q quit when one terminal window closes.

I don't know how Amazon Q handles signals, but the first thing you could try is using open -W -a '/Applications/Amazon Q.app and see whether it closes if you close the tab (without running q quit).
If this doesn't work, the following will:

Create a shell function in whatever startup file you use for zsh:

function run_q() {
    Q_STARTED_FROM_HERE=yes
    open '/Applications/Amazon Q.app'
}


Add the folloing to ~/.zlogout:

if [[ "$Q_STARTED_FROM_HERE" == yes ]]; then
    q quit
fi


Then use run_q to start the application. It will close when you quit the tab you started it from.


The ~/.zlogout file doesn't seem to work. Apart from the fact that it didn't exist on my system without me creating it myself, q quit just doesn't run. It's fine though as I've sort of given up on this. I'm okay with having to open up the program every time now - at least it won't surprise me. Thanks anyways.

While this is not an answer to the specific question, it may be an answer to the general question, "When quitting App1 how can I automatically quit App2?"
I use the LLM coding assistant Continue with VS Code (Continue is a VS Code extension), and I use Ollama to run LLMs locally, with Continue configured to use Ollama. A usage scenario I believe is similar to that of the question.
I use a Keyboard Maestro macro set up such that when VS Code launches, Ollama will be launched. And when VS Code quits, Ollama is quit.
As I noted in a comment above this does require an additional tool, and may not be allowed in a corporate environment. This would solve the underlying issue of the question, quitting Amazon Q when iTerm quits, without concern for the launching and exiting of individual shells.
